# Shotwell stopped working after upgrading Ubuntu (14.04 to 15.10)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.10, shotwell

I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.10 and when I tried to open Shotwell, I only got the following message (Shotwell main window not even starts):

> Your photo library is not compatible with this version of Shotwell. 
>   It appears it was created by Shotwell 0.1.1 (schema 21).  This version
>   is 0.22.0 (schema 20).  Please use the latest version of Shotwell.

However, as far as I know, 0.22.0 already is the latest version of Shotwell (as its main page says). So, I ask if is there a way to upgrade (or make compatible) my photo library.

I appreciate any help very much!

Comment: try removing `~/.cache/shotwell` and let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem (though I recently upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04). I fixed it by going into ~/.local/share/shotwell & renaming the `data` folder to `data.bak` (alternately you could delete it but you'll have no chance to recover it in the future).

My old database is gone, but I can now open Shotwell & rebuild the database.